# How JavaScript's (0 == "") === true agrees with ECMA-262 type conversion rules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma262

I've already seen several questions explaining why `0 == ""` is `true` in **JavaScript**, but i have a bit deeper question.

So the answer to why is `0 == ""` is `true` in JavaScript is that string `""` gets converted to number, zero-length string is converted to zero number, but how this agrees with `[9.3.1 paragraph of ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1)` which says that string should be parsed using given formal grammar and if it fails, then such string is converted to `NaN`. When i looked on this spec i thought that `""` is not a string numeric literal and it should be parsed as `NaN` and `NaN` is not equal to `0.0`.

So why above speculation isn't correct and `0 == ""` is actually `true`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0.*

Comment: Oh, thanks. I need to be more attentive. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar allows for *StringNumericLiteral* to be empty:

> *StringNumericLiteral* :::
>       ***StrWhiteSpace*<sub>opt</sub>**
>       *StrWhiteSpace*<sub>opt</sub> *StrNumericLiteral* *StrWhiteSpace*<sub>opt</sub>

A few lines down, it says:

> A *StringNumericLiteral* that is empty or contains only white space is converted to **+0**.

and:

> The MV of *StringNumericLiteral* ::: [empty] is 0.

So I'm afraid you simply didn't fully read the standard passage you're looking at. :)

Comment: As well as "Some differences should be noted between the syntax of a StringNumericLiteral and a NumericLiteral (see 7.8.3): ...
A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0."

Comment: I wonder why they bothered with two productions in the main _StringNumericLiteral_ entry. They could have just added _opt_ after _StrNumericLiteral_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the *StrWhiteSpace(opt) StrNumericLiteral StrWhiteSpace(opt)* allows for consecutive white space.

Comment: Yes it does, because _StrWhiteSpace_ can be multiple whitespace characters.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh yes, so it can! Then, yeah, I don't see why either. Perhaps they figured it makes the individual "use cases" clearer.

Comment: @Barmar: I would think the *HexIntegerLiteral* needs to be excluded when referencing the string numeric literal elsewhere in the spec.

Comment: Oh, indeed. OK, so i need to be more attentive. :) Thanks.

But why didn't they add `StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty]` to the grammar description? Something like `StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] | StrWhiteSpaceopt | StrWhiteSpaceopt StrNumericLiteral StrWhiteSpaceopt`?

Comment: @yaromir: They didn't need to. Those "opt" mean the whitespace is _optional_, so the grammar already allows for the empty production.